# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, mysql, wordpress

I have a Linux server (Centos 7) running WordPress and another Linux server (Ubuntu) running MySQL. Communication between WordPress and the Database was working. However, after a web server reboot, I see the following message in the browser:

[This site can't be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JIrC.jpg)

It was determined that Apache was not running via: **ps -ef | grep http**

I manually started Apache via: **service httpd start**

***** I do want Apache to start automatically after a server reboot *****

Now Apache returned the following message in the browser: **Error establishing a database connection**

After attempting to test the connecting via: **mysql**

Linux returned the error: **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

The directory, '/var/lib/mysql/', is empty. I read on the Internet, that when the MySQL service runs, it creates the socket. When exited, the socket file is removed. Not sure this is true or not.

So it appears to be a MySQL socket issue.

Looking forward to everybody's help on this...

Comment: If the mysql server is on a different host, then you cannot connect through a socket. Your web application may have lost its database configuration. Enabling Apache as a service is `chkconfig --add httpd` I think on Centos 7. Connect to a different host: `mysql -h hostname -u user -p`

Comment: How to check if the web server lost its database configuration?

Comment: Depends on the application. Often it is something like `config/config.php` or `config/database.php` etc.

Comment: I have Wordpress and PHP installed. I am able to access the databse on the DB server from the Web server successfully via: `mysql -u dbuser -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p`

Comment: Should be wp-config.php in the root of the webdirectory, right at the front. DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST

Comment: The DB, USER, PASSWORD info is correct in the `wp-config.php` file. I did notice that mysqld is not running. Failed to start it via `service mysql restart`. Would installing mysql fix this?

Comment: Which server are  you talking about when you say that mysql server is not running? Where does the DB_HOST setting in wp-config.php point to?

Comment: mysqld is not running on the web server. I thought the service is suppose to run so the wordPress can use it. Can you explain how WordPress, PHP, and the DB connector works?

Comment: Wordpress needs a database to store pages and other things which are not files. The settings for the connection are in the wp-config.php, and usually they get there when you install wordpress. If DB_HOST points to localhost or the webserver name then it uses a locally installed database, else it uses a database on another host.

Comment: DB_HOST is pointing to the DB server along with the DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD. Does WordPress need a mysql service enabled or running?

Comment: Yes, on the server that DB_HOST is pointing to.

Comment: If centos has selinux enabled, then you may need to execute this command to remove a block on connection over the network to mysql: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`. You can see it it is enabled in the output of `sestatus` in the line current mode. If it is `enforcing` then it can block connections.

Comment: And maybe `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` if connect_db does not work and selinux is in enforcing mode.

Comment: I reverted the server back to a 2-day snapshot and it works. The WordPress site was re-loaded into the database.  The `sestatus` reported `Current mode: enforcing`. I plan to reboot the server, hoping that it will work. Is there a way to see if the following is already set on the server before I issue the command? `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Comment: Yes with `getsebool httpd_can_network_connect`. Maybe selinux went into enforcing mode after a reboot.

Comment: The result of `getsebool httpd_can_network_connect` is `off`

Comment: We issued the command `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1' and it WORKS!!! Can you post the answer to the question so I can assign a check mark? Now I have to deal with another issue - BackupGuard needs permission to write to a WordPress directory.

Comment: Will we need to issue the command `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` every time we reboot the server?

Comment: No, with the `-P` the setting will stay. The problem is probably that before it was done only without `-P` then it only stays until the next selinux booleans commit or reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Centos/Red Hat/Fedora/Suse, and you have things that seem to work as root or other logged in user but not from an application like a webserver, then check if your instance has selinux on with `sestatus`.

`sestatus`

```
SELinux status: enabled
SELinuxfs mount: /selinux
Current Mode: enforcing
```

If it is in mode *enforcing* then you can check audit logs to see if your problem is there. For example to see errors from something running in the `httpd` program:

```
ausearch -c "httpd" -m AVC,USER_AVC,SELINUX_ERR,USER_SELINUX_ERR -i
```

And/or use:

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log > /path/to/mylogfile.txt
```

For some common problems there exist *booleans* to tweak the working of the default policies. For a complete listing use `getsebool -a`

For httpd servers you have an option for accessing specifically some common database ports over network, `httpd_can_network_connect_db` and  more generic full network access, `httpd_can_network_connect`. This applies if you use php as a module in httpd and it has to access a database over network connection.

If you wan't to change them you use `setsebool -P <boolean_name_> {0|1|on|off}`. Without the `-P` the setting will revert on reboot.

An excellent starting point if you do want to read up on selinux: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux